# why setstate not working in react js in after selection item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my `setState` function not working properly as it is not rendering the component.

set to reproduce.

1. select any area . example see below image first-row second column.
2. see the update row data on the console.now I am trying  to update view using updated data but it's is not reflecting .

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-4cu5p

[image]

if

```
onUpdate: args => {
            const { startCell, topLeft, bottomRight } = args;
            const { idx: topLeftColumn, rowIdx: topLeftRowIdx } = topLeft;
            const { idx: startColumn, rowIdx: startRowIndex } = startCell;
            const { idx: bottomColumn, rowIdx: bottomRowIndex } = bottomRight;

            const rows = this.state.rows.slice();
            console.log(this.state.rows[startRowIndex][keys[startColumn]]);
            let item = this.state.rows[startRowIndex][keys[startColumn]];

            console.log(topLeftRowIdx, "topLeftRowIdx");
            console.log(bottomRowIndex, "bottomRowIndex");
            console.log(topLeftColumn, "topLeftColumn");
            console.log(bottomColumn, "bottomColumn");
            for (var i = topLeftRowIdx; i <= bottomRowIndex; i++) {
              for (var j = topLeftColumn; j <= bottomColumn; j++) {
                console.log("----");
                rows[i][keys[j]] = item;
              }
            }
            console.log(rows);
            this.setState({
              rows: [...rows]
            });

            //  this.setState({
            //   rows:[
            //     { id: 0, title: "Task 1ssss", complete: "Task 2" },
            //     { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: "Task 3" },
            //     { id: 2, title: "Task 3", complete: "Task 4" }
            //   ]
            //  });
            console.log(this.state);
            return rows;
          },
```

if i do hard coded `setState` which is commented out code then it works

```
//  this.setState({
            //   rows:[
            //     { id: 0, title: "Task 1ssss", complete: "Task 2" },
            //     { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: "Task 3" },
            //     { id: 2, title: "Task 3", complete: "Task 4" }
            //   ]
            //  });
```

above code works after selection area and it updates the view when I uncomment the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to array deep copy:

from

```
 this.setState({
              rows: [...rows]
        });
```

to

```
   this.setState({
      rows: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))
    });
```

More efficient way to copy item in loop :

```
 for (var i = topLeftRowIdx; i <= bottomRowIndex; i++) {
              for (var j = topLeftColumn; j <= bottomColumn; j++) {
                console.log("----");
                rows[i][keys[j]] = item;
              }
              rows[i] = { ...rows[i]};
            }
```